# jQuery touch slider plugin with variable width

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, slider

I have spent the better half of the afternoon googleing for this with no luck and so have resorted to asking here.

I am in search of a jQuery slider plugin that has the following features:

- responsive
- touch / ios friendly
- will allow variable width slides

I have found one that is close to my needs but does not support touch here:
http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php

The site I am working on currently is here: http://joeholt.co.uk/design/lilys-kitchen/. This shows how the final result should look but currently it does not allow variable width slides. I am using http://bxslider.com/ for this at the moment. In a perfect world I would be able to just place vimeo embeds in there too but I can work around that.

Answer (score 0):

[This one](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) works great! It also supports touch very well.

EDIT:

With [this jQuery touch swipe plugin](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin), the following code might work.

```
$('.slider-wrapper').swipe({
    swipeRight:function() {
        $('.bx-prev').click();
    },  
    swipeLeft:function() {
        $('.bx-next').click();
    }
});
```

I know it's primitive but it might just do the job.

Comment: That does look nice but does it support different sized slides?

Comment: No, sorry. This is only a solution for the touch support. Without the variable width for the items [this](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/carousel-min-max.html) would be the best way to go.

Comment: I might have a solution, give me a few more minutes and I'll let you know.

Comment: With the swipe plugin it clicks the next or previous button when you swipe left or right on the slider

Comment: If you take a look at my current example. http://joeholt.co.uk/design/lilys-kitchen/ it swipes on ipad fine it just won't allow me to have variable width slides

Comment: Then I suggest to use the lemmon juice plugin with the code shown above. Just replace the class-names with the ones that are used by the lemon juice slider.

Comment: lemmonjuice doesn't support swipe though?

Answer (score 0):

This one should work too (variableWidth: true):
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/